# How to get the options inside ng-select in angular2 or typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-select

i have installed angular2-select and have defined that in module.ts as well. But when i click on select button, there are 2 contents but the contents are not visible, can anyone help me to solve this.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label >Category Type</label>
<ng-select [options]="category" [(ngModel)]="category.name" name="category" class='filterDropDown' placeholder="Category" notFoundMsg="No Category Found">
 </ng-select>
 </div>
```

ts:
category:any = [{name:'school'},{name:'college'}];

Comment: Will you please create a plnkr for this ?

Comment: I have no idea to create plunker, can i share pics, how it is coming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `angular-2 select`, the `options` take in `items array`

Also, use `ng-2 select` instead of `angular-2 select`

```
import {SelectModule} from 'ng2-select'
```

According to its documentation here, [official documentation](https://valor-software.com/ng2-select/) it requires,

**`items - (Array<any>) - Array of items from which to select. Should be an array of objects with id and text properties. As convenience, you may also pass an array of strings, in which case the same string is used for both the ID and the text.`**

So, your object shoud be either,

```
category:any = [{ id: 'school', text:'school'},{id: 'college', text:'college'}];

<ng-select [items]="category" [(ngModel)]="category.id" name="category" class='filterDropDown' placeholder="Category" notFoundMsg="No Category Found">
 </ng-select>

or

category:any = ['school', 'college'];

<ng-select [items]="category" [(ngModel)]="category" name="category" class='filterDropDown' placeholder="Category" notFoundMsg="No Category Found">
 </ng-select>
```

**PS:** You can use `angular2-select` change the object to,

```
import {SelectModule} from 'angular2-select'
```

**It uses, value and label and use same `[options]` in html**

```
category:any = [{ label: 'school', value:'school'},{label: 'college', value:'college'}];

<ng-select [options]="category" [(ngModel)]="category.label" name="category" class='filterDropDown' placeholder="Category" notFoundMsg="No Category Found">
 </ng-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-select [**items**]="category" [(ngModel)]="category.name" name="category" class='filterDropDown' placeholder="Category" notFoundMsg="No Category Found">
```

It is items not options

Comment: Thanks for the response, if i use items instead of options, i get this error " Can't bind to 'items' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-select'. "